# JMETER - Can't catch a 'token' with blankspace

Tags: javascript, java, jmeter

Being faster, I can't catch a "token" because have a blank space in the name. How can i fetch them?

The result:

```js
{
    "result": {
        "returnCode": "success",
        **"model code": "3b6car5tphkvkhp3a5"**
    }
}
```

[image: Here what im doing]

The jmeter doesnt catch because have a blank space in model( )code. So, how can I catch the token?

Really Thank you guys!

Comment: Quoting the field name with single quotes as in `$..'model code'` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to extract the value.

[image]

JSON Path Expression is `['result']['model code']`